# Caching in dll for asp.net site?

Tags: asp.net

I have a .NET DLL on my site.  I'd like to use Cache() like you can on ASP.net websites, but it's just a class library project.

I'm guessing I'm missing a reference but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look the the [System.Runtime.Caching Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching%28VS.100%29.aspx) (assuming you're using .Net4)

"The classes in this namespace provide a way to use caching facilities like those in ASP.NET, but without a dependency on the System.Web assembly"